# Move Icon Disappears from Categories editor

Tags: categories, control-panel

The move symbol -  the one that allows you to move a category in the list up or down, etc. -- is gone from one of my category groups.  It's the one that appears just after the checkbox to select a category and right before the name of a category.

How do I get it back?

I know, stupid question. But I have no clue what I did to make it disappear.  The other category groups are okay.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh...never mind.  I guess I took it off structure without realizing it.